# 2 factor authentication

Tags: magento2

I am trying to implement 2 factor authentication. After the default customer login, I have redirected to a new page where my 2nd authentication is checked.

But the problem is,since the user is already authenticated,he can redirect to any page from the address bar.

Is there a way I could delay the session setting till my 2nd factor is also authenticated.

I tried putting custom sessions in controller dispatch. But the problem is,I am unsetting the session in the phtml where the authentication is happening. But somehow this session unsetting is happening as soon the phtml is loaded. Cant figure out that part either.

My controllerAction predispatch file. The problem with this is the redirect to login page after customer session destruction is not working.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Customer;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;
use Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use MSP\TwoFactorAuth\Api\TfaInterface;
use MSP\TwoFactorAuth\Api\TfaSessionInterface;
use MSP\TwoFactorAuth\Api\TrustedManagerInterface;

class ControllerActionPredispatch implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TfaInterface
     */
    private $tfa;

    /**
     * @var ActionFlag
     */
    private $actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var TfaSessionInterface
     */
    private $tfaSession;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var TrustedManagerInterface
     */
    private $trustedManager;
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;


    public function __construct(
        TfaInterface $tfa,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        UrlInterface $url,
        Session $session,
        TfaSessionInterface $tfaSession,
        TrustedManagerInterface $trustedManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
    ) {
        $this->tfa = $tfa;
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->tfaSession = $tfaSession;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->trustedManager = $trustedManager;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;

    }

    /**
     * Get current user
     * @return \Magento\User\Model\User|null
     */
    private function getUser()
    {
        return $this->session->getUser();
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // if (!$this->tfa->isEnabled()) {
        //     return;
        // }

        /** @var $controllerAction \Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); //Get customer object
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $fullActionName = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $char=$this->customerSession->getMyValue();
        echo $char;
        if(is_null($char)){
            echo "null aane";
        return;}
        elseif ($char=="notatallsuper") {
            echo "hello";
                    //$customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
                    //$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
                    $this->customerSession->unsMyValue();
                    $this->customerSession->destroy();
                    $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');
                    $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

        }

    }
}
```

My phtml file

```
<style>
    .form-horizontal {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .bold125 {
        font-size: 125%;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .bold150 {
        font-size: 150%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .image-fido {
        border: none;
        margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .image-touch {
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>

<?php

$result =  $block->getdevicelist();
$dropdown = "";
//$myJSON = json_encode($result);
?>

<fieldset>

     <div class="form-horizontal">
     Please select your yubikey device
       <!-- <p>
       <input type="button"
           style="margin:10px 0;"
               onclick="populateSelect()"
                   value="Click to Populate SELECT with JSON" />
   </p> -->

   <!--The SELECT element.-->
   <select id="sel">

       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
       <?php
       foreach ($result as $value) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $value['Value'] ?>"><?php echo  $value['Text'];?></option>
         <?php
       }
       ?>

   </select>
   <p id="msg"></p>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
 <div id="registration-modal">
     <div id="registration-modal-text">
     </div>

     <div id="registration-modal-img">
         <img src="" id="loading-img" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
     </div>
 </div>
 <script src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::js/lib/u2f-api.js'); ?>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function($,modal) {
//  var base_url="https://127.0.0.1";
var base_url= "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl_without_index();?>";
$("#sel").change(function() {
  show(this);
})
function show(ele) {
        // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
       var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Selected Bird: <b>' + ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text + '</b> </br>' +
           'ID: <b>' + ele.value + '</b>';
          var id = (ele.value).toString();
          // var base_url= "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl_without_index();?>";
          // console.log("base"+base_url);
          console.log(id);
          authentication(id);
        }

function authentication(device_id)
{
           console.log(device_id);
          var customurl ='https://api.hopponapp.com/YubiKey/api/Account/VerifyFido';
          $.ajax({
              url: customurl,
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data:{
                "Text":"",
                "Value":device_id,
                "Userid":"",
                "Appid":base_url
              },
          complete: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#registration-modal').modal({
                type: 'popup',
                title: 'FIDO Security Key Registration',
                buttons: []
            }).css({
                "paddingBottom": 15,
                "text-align": "center",
            }).modal('openModal');
            var u2f_model=
            {
              device_name:"",
              user_id:"",
              challenge:"",
              app_id:"",
              version:"",
              keyHandle: "",
              clientData: "",
              signatureData: ""
            }
               var challenge = response.responseJSON.Model.Challenge;
               var app_id = response.responseJSON.Model.AppId;
               var version = response.responseJSON.Model.Version ;
               var key_handle= response.responseJSON.Model.KeyHandle;
               var user_id=response.responseJSON.Model.UserID;
               var device=response.responseJSON.Model.DeviceName;
               console.log("dattttaa");
               console.log(device);
              if(response.responseJSON.Response=="TOUCHYUBIKEY")
              {
                      $('#registration-modal-text').text("Please confirm user presence NOW");
                      $(document).ready(function () {
                       if (window.chrome === undefined) {
                           alert("Chrome is currently the only browser that supports FIDO U2F");
                           history.back();
                       }
                       if (window.u2f === undefined) {
                           alert("Chrome extension for FIDO U2F is not intalled");
                           history.back();
                       }
                   });

                   var errorMap = {
                       1: 'Unknown error, try again',
                       2: "Bad request error, try again",
                       3: "This key isn't supported, please try another one",
                       4: 'The key handle is invalid',
                       5: 'Authentication timed out. Please reload to try again.'
                   };

                   // Define an object to READ from the API
                   var fido = {
                       keyHandle: "",
                       clientData: "",
                       signatureData: ""
                   }

                   var myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                 //var base_url= "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl_without_index();?>";

                 console.log(base_url);
                       window.u2f.sign([
                           {
                               challenge:challenge ,
                               version:version,
                               appId:base_url,
                               keyHandle:key_handle
                           }
                       ], function (data) {
                           clearTimeout(myTimeout);
                           if (data.errorCode) {
                               alert(errorMap[data.errorCode] + '\n(Error code #' + data.errorCode + ')');
                              // window.history.back();
                           } else {
                               // put the data in a structure
                               fido = data;
                              u2f_model.user_id=user_id;
                              u2f_model.challenge=challenge;
                              u2f_model.version=version;
                              u2f_model.device_name=device;
                              u2f_model.app_id=base_url;
                              u2f_model.keyHandle=fido.keyHandle;
                              u2f_model.clientData=fido.clientData;
                              u2f_model.signatureData=fido.signatureData;
                               // fill the form and submit
                               console.log(u2f_model);
                               deviceauth(u2f_model);
                           }
                       });
                    }, 100);
              }
              else {
                $('#registration-modal-text').text("Device Error");

              }
          // Define an object to READ from the API}

              },
              error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                  console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
              }
          });
          var deviceauth=function (obj)
          {
            console.log(obj);
            var device_id_string=device_id.toString();
            var customurl ='https://api.hopponapp.com/YubiKey/api/Account/VerifyFidoSign';
            // user_id:"",
            // challenge:"",
            // app_id:"",
            // version:"",
            // keyHandle: "",
            // clientData: "",
            // signatureData: ""
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                  "FidoDevicesArray":"",
                  "FidoDevicesSelect":"",
                  "ID":device_id_string,
                  "UserID":obj.user_id,
                  "DeviceName":obj.device_name,
                  "AppId":obj.app_id,
                  "KeyHandle":obj.keyHandle,
                  "Version":obj.version,
                  "Challenge":obj.challenge,
                  "clientData":obj.clientData,
                  "signatureData":obj.signatureData
                },
            complete: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if(response.responseJSON.Response=="Success")
            {
              console.log("isitsucces?");
              <?php $block->unsetsessoinvalue();?>;
              var url= "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>/magento";
              console.log(url);
              document.location.href=url;


            }
            else {
              $('#registration-modal-text').text(response.responseJSON.Response);

            }

          },
          error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
              console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
          }

      });
    }
    }

   });
</script>
```

Comment: You can use predispatch event to restrict the user to access any page unless your condition pass.

Comment: That what I have done. But I have also done a customer session unset in my phtml file after the authentication which is being unset immediately after the page is loaded. I have added the code. It would be great if you could take a look